# assigning the same value to all strings in dataframe

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I need to assign some values to strings in my dataset. My dataframe looks like:

```
Network1 Network2
A        A
A        C
B        D
```

I would like for all values to be consistent so if A =1 in network 1 it should be 1 also in network 2

I tried the following:

```
data$network1<-as.numeric(as.factor(data$network1))
data$network2<-as.numeric(as.factor(data$network2))
```

But the values that are attached do not match except for a few cases.

Is there any way I could just do this globally for both columns at the same time so the values are consistent? I would like the desired output to be:

```
Network1 network2
1                1
1                3
2                4
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you post desired output ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unlist`, convert it into `factor`, then `numeric` and back to original form

```
df[] <- as.numeric(factor(unlist(df)))

df
#  Network1 Network2
#1        1        1
#2        1        3
#3        2        4
```

Answer (score 2):

You can save all the levels of the data frame first :

```
df <- data.frame(Network1 = c("A", "A", "B"), Network2 = c("A", "C", "D"))

lvls <- unique(unlist(df))

df$Network1 <- as.numeric(factor(df$Network1, levels = lvls))
df$Network2 <- as.numeric(factor(df$Network2, levels = lvls))
df

>   Network1 Network2
 1        1        1
 2        1        3
 3        2        4
```

Answer (score 2):

Could also try:

```
strings <- unique(unlist(df))
matchdf <- data.frame(strings, as.numeric(as.factor(strings)))

as.data.frame(sapply(df, function(x) match(x, matchdf$strings)))
```

Output:

```
  Network1 Network2
1        1        1
2        1        3
3        2        4
```

This will apply the logic to all columns at once.